# Xcode TabBar controller logout issue

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase

I have a tab bar controller in my app. one of the tabs has a navigation Controller with a bar button. clicking the bar button segues to a tableViewController which has another button in it. The button segues to yet another TableViewController which includes a logout button.

```
    @IBAction func logoutDidTap(_ sender: Any) {
            try! FIRAuth.auth()?.signOut()
```

when I login to the app again and click on that tab, it takes me to the TableViewController with the logout button instead of the beginning of the tab. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have placed all the view controllers under the navigation controller, so you can easily pop them from the navigation stack when you are done logging out. Here's how to do it:-

```
    @IBAction fund logoutDidTap(sender:Any){
    try! FirAuth.auth()?.signout()

var viewControllers = navigationController?.viewControllers
viewControllers?.removeLast(2) // views to pop
navigationController?.setViewControllers(viewControllers!, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: up vote accept it as answer then for other people to help while searching.. Thanks :)

Comment: I would but I don't have enough reputation for it to matter

Comment: when you'll have, come back and do it :)